Installing ubuntu 24.04 encrypted, along with Windows with BitLocker on the same hard drive
I've attempted to install Ubuntu Beta 24.04 on a new laptop that originally came with Windows 11 Home and disk encryption enabled (BitLocker). During the installation process, the installer raised an issue regarding BitLocker, so I temporarily disabled it in order to proceed with the Ubuntu installation. Following this, Ubuntu was able to detect the disk, offering options to either install alongside Windows (Option 1), erase the entire hard drive (Option 2), or proceed with manual configuration (Option 3).
However, I encountered difficulty in finding a way within Options 1 or 3 to install Ubuntu on a partition and encrypt it.
While there are several tutorials available for Ubuntu 22.04, they appear to be lengthy do-it-yourself guides.
I'm wondering if the stable release of Ubuntu 24.04 will address this common scenario.
Thank you.

If you think this is a bug in the installer, please report the bug using the proper bug reporting channel. It is not clear what you meant by: "However, I encountered difficulty in finding a way within Options 1". Can you provide some screenshots with more details?

I don't know if it is a bug or simple a feature not implemented. I mean, that with option 1, Ubuntu installer will automatically resize the partition and chose boot/efi but it it will NOT encrypt the new partition. With Option 3, same: I can pick a partition but canner tell Ubuntu to encrypt it . And If I manually create an ext2 inside LUKS, Ubuntu installer will not let me choose it... Does it make sense ?

I have not tried the new installer yet. So I can't tell you my experience. If you are using the beta/daily download today, I doubt it will be fixed when it comes out tomorrow. The encryption is supposed to be "whole disk" (except for the ESP and boot partitions). So that may be why it does not come up with dual boot installs. But that's my guess.

The beta image is very old... (20240410.2 for example for Ubuntu Desktop amd64, where current is 20240424) so you should test with a current ISO (currently RC too).

ok.. it looks like the new disk partition used in the new install doesn't support LUKS... so apparently the workaround is using 22.04 and then upgrade...

I was able to install the released version of 24.04 LTS with Windows 10 and Ubuntu LUKS, using the installer.  On "How do you want to install Ubuntu?", select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", then select LVM and encryption for advanced features.  Then go back and select "Install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10."

waw... @Guangliang  really ???? it worked without losing Windows ??.... nice.. !!  at the end I installed it along Windows but NOT encrypted... and encrypted only my home directory (not what I wanted...)

@user68186 Sorry I didn't take screen shots during the installation and don't know how to re-create the screen shots without re-do the installation process.

See also https://askubuntu.com/q/1520882/288322.

As @guangliang mentioned in his/her comment the steps are

Disable bitlocker
Run installer
Select erase disk
Select LVN with encryption
Click back
Install along
Drink a coffee
Boot windows from bios (not from grub)
Enable bitlucker
Celebrate


Do you have to do step 8 every time once the encryption is on or is it only required when turning the encryption on?

Yep... Windows need to booted from the bios....

If the recovery key has been lost, Ubuntu can be installed after cleaning the encrypted Windows-drive:

When asked for the BitLocker key, select the option Press Esc for
more recovery options.
If asked a second time, choose Skip this drive.
Next choose Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Command
Prompt.
Write diskpart in the command prompt, then, list disk to find the number of the primary disk. Select the primary disk, e.g. select disk=<number of primary disk>. Clean the selected disk using clean disk. Ready!
Exit the command promt and restart the
computer. Then, start the Ubuntu installation.


I had a different problem (BitLocker recovery key available, but no Windows installed) and the Ubuntu 24.04.1 installer did not manage to install Ubuntu, not even choosing the option to erase the entire contents of the hard drive and to create Ubuntu's own structure as explained in https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#13-additional-installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows-with-bitlocker. However, your solution worked perfectly fine, thanks!
